# How to calculate characters remaining in multiple text area

Tags: jquery, input, character, textarea

Hello i wanted to calculate characters remaining in multiple text area boxes using jquery, it works, but i want to calculate each box solely, and i know the problem of duplicating results that because i use the same class of the div,
sorry i am new
is there any good way to fix this without using different classes and repeating scripts 4 times? because that's not logical ?

```js
$(function() {
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
 var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength'),
     textLength =  $(this).val().length,
     remText    = ( maxLength - textLength );
     $('.text').html(remText + ' characters remaining')

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea  maxlength="20"></textarea> 
<div class='text'></div>

<textarea  maxlength="20"></textarea> 
<div class='text'></div>

<textarea  maxlength="20"></textarea> 
<div class='text'></div>

<textarea  maxlength="20"></textarea> 
<div class='text'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate the instance using a traversal method like [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength'),
      textLength = $(this).val().length,
      remText = (maxLength - textLength);
    $(this).next('.text').html(remText + ' characters remaining');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
<div class='text'></div>

<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
<div class='text'></div>

<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
<div class='text'></div>

<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
<div class='text'></div>
```

Comment: saved my time, thanks, another question please, i found an answer while searching that it can be done by data-value.,? what data-value is? and how it solves the problem? thanks

Comment: where's link to other solution?